# Modular Arithmetic $bxp \equiv ayp \pmod{p^2} \quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I need to solve
$$bxp \equiv ayp \pmod{p^2} \quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{N}$$
with $a,b,p \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p$ being prime, to find a relation between $a$ and $b$.

I have tried using the equations $axp \equiv 0 \pmod{p^2}$ and $byp \equiv 0 \pmod{p^2}$ that I get when I let $x$ and $y$ be $0$ separately, but that didn't seem to help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have $bx \equiv ay$ (mod p), it has a solution $(a,b)$ ;)

Comment: what does (a,b) mean?

Comment: $(a,b)$ is an ordered pair.